# how to store function pointers in array

Tags: c, function, struct, function-pointers, typedef

```
typedef int (*t_built)(t_cmds *, t_table *);

struct cmdline
{
   char *      reserved[7]; /* "echo pwd cd unset export exit env" */
   t_built     builtin[7];
}
```

How can I store my builtin functions into builtin array with same indexes as in reserved array. Can you help me to understand how this syntax works and for what declared typedef for function pointer.

Comment: IMO, It is easier to understand function type rather function pointer type was `typedef`-ed. `typedef int t_build(t_cmds*, t_table*); t_build *builtin[7];`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose the declarations:

```
int f(int);
```

declares `f` as a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`.

This can be written with parentheses (this is useless here but harmless):

```
int (f)(int);
```

The following declaration:

```
int *f(int);
```

declares `f` as a function taking an `int` and returning a pointer to an `int`.

This time, parentheses change the order of evaluation:

```
int (*f)(int);
```

declares `f` as a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`.

`typedef` is used to define a type instead of a variable.

Finally the sequence:

```
typedef int (*f)(int);
f a[7];
```

declares `a` as an array of seven elements of type `f`, `f` describing a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`.

By the way, there is a converter for that sort of things: [cdecl: C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org/).